# Importing existing database into new Dokku application

Tags: postgresql, dokku

I have an existing application that I am trying to port over to [Dokku](https://dokku.com/docs/getting-started/installation/), and part of that is getting the existing data store copied over. I am using the [Dokku Postgres plugin](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres), but am having trouble getting the database ported over.

In my existing app I am creating a dump of the database:

```sh
// Create dump file
pg_dump app_database > db.dump

// Copy over to server hosting Dokku app
scp db.dump sshdetails

// SSH into new server, then attempt to import dump file
dokku postgres:import db < db.dump
```

When I run the last command, I get the message:
`pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`

I have tried formatting the dump in a few different formats but no luck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What where the other `pg_dump` commands you tried and what where the errors when you tried to restore them? Add answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source of `dokku postgres:export` command in [dokku-postgres](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres/blob/b794db26f85ca1f2c04c37f62f386d513445e61a/functions#L107) plugin :

```
docker exec "$SERVICE_NAME" env PGPASSWORD="$PASSWORD" pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -w "$DATABASE_NAME"
```

The `dokku postgres:export` command have `-Fc` argument for `pg_dump` which export dump as archive suitable for input into `pg_restore` (more information into [pg_dump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pg_dump) man page) and `pg_restore` command seems to only accept custom format from `pg_dump` (cf. [pg_restore](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pg_restore) man), so you should use the same `-Fc` argument in `pg_dump` command.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Seems obvious in hindsight I should have just read the source for the export command.